# How to open an existing project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, project

I have just created several project using Eclipse. Now restart Eclipse and want to see one of the projects. How can I do it?

I have tried File -> Import -> General -> Existing Project into Workspace.

Then I select the directory of the project that I want to work on and, as a result, I get an error message: "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace".

So, it looks like that I do not need to import a project, because they are already in the workspace... But how I can "see" the projects that are in the workspace? If I create a new project, I see it as well as all other existing projects but I do not want to create a new project just to see the existing projects.

Comment: Can you find it in the 'Navigator' view?

Comment: In the navigator view I do not see "Open Project". I see there "Open Element", "Open Type in Hierarchy" and so on...

Comment: If you find Eclipse extremely counter-intuitive as I do, you might want to switch to NetBeans (which is very bugged, but at least it's intuitive to use, at least for me). I too cannot figure out how Eclipse opens existing projects and not sure I even want to investigate any further.

Comment: argg... "buggy" not "bugged"

Comment: Eclipse: making it mind boggling difficult to open files since the 2000s.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you have closed the project and configured the project explorer view to filter closed projects.

In that case, have a look at [Filters in the Project Explorer view](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcjviewfilters.html). Make sure that closed projects are disabled in the "Filters" view.

Comment: First I need to find out how I can open the "Project Explorer View" (may be there I will see my projects?).

Comment: Yes, I figured out how to open the Project Explorer View and there I see what I needed (all my projects).

Comment: To summarize, I did not configured the project explorer to filter something. It is just not opened by default in Eclipse (at least in those version that I use).

Answer (score 4):

In case you closed multiple projects and trying to re-open all of them then in Windows->Show view-> Navigator

Answer (score 3):

from Eclipse main gui:
select "Window->Show View->Other->General->Project Explorer" Double-clicking on "Project Explorer" brings up the  "Project Explorer" window which shows every project in your workspace. That worked for me.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just do like below, it helped me after doing like this.

To load existing Eclipse projects in the IDE, you need to import them into the Eclipse workspace.

1. Click File > Import > General
2. Click Existing Projects into Workspace.
3. You can edit the project directly in its original location or choose to create a copy of the project in the workspace.
4. Select the directory that contains the projects you want to import.
5. Click Finish.
   This imports the projects into the current workspace and loads them in the IDE.

Look at this below link for reference.
https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/enterprise-developer/ed30/Eclipse/GUID-773A19C7-98B2-442D-9D36-240E20E3F2CE.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to import non maven project into eclipse follow the below steps, it worked for me.

first clone project into your machine and follow the below steps to import in eclipse.

> Project Explorer -> import -> Git -> Projects from git -> Existing
> Local repository -> Add -> select project root directory -> (check
> box) import as general project -> next -> finish

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, try Project > Open Project and select the projects to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

In case you closed multiple projects and trying to re-open all of them then in `Project Explorer`, select all projects. Go to `Project` -> `Open Project`.

Answer (score 0):

I also have just faced with this problem that how to open existing file. And none of answers was helpful. That's why I tried by myself.

> Direction: File -> Open file -> Workspace (with you had chosen first
>   in creating your project) -> Package (which you already created your
>   project in) -> src (source file) -> Created package ->

And now your searching project's nodepad format. 
I hope it would be helpful. If any mistake here, sorry beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This is How I do it.

File -> Open Project from File System -> Existing Project in WorkSpace

Answer (score 0):

Use shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or navigate to Windows->Show View->Project Explorer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to an older question with existing answers it may be useful to point out in your answer what version of Eclipse this answer applies to as it appears that the menu structure has changed in the seven years since the question was asked. Similarly if Eclipse has different menu names on different operating systems it may be worth mentioning which OSs this applies to.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a maven project, go to file>import>maven project >existing maven project, then browse for the folder that contains the project, select folder then click finish. That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you closed the project, you can open it again easily by going to the top bar (alt) > ͟Project > Open Project
[Top menu > Project > Open Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmNPG.png)
You will get a menu where you can open closed projects that can be preventing you from opening these projects through the File menu.
[The window that lets you open any closed projects after you go through the menu listed previously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM9I4.png)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after I deleted `.classpath` and `.project` files from the directory

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Method it will work:**

1. In Top Right Corner Click on `Open Prospective` icon.
   [image: Open Prospective]
2. Click on `Java (Default)` in Popup.
   [image]
3. Click on `Open` button.

**Courtesy:**  [www.softans.com](https://www.softans.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 'Eclipse IDE 2022‑09'

1. Click the View Menu on the Package Explorer

[image]

2. Filters...
3. Uncheck the "Closed projects"

Or you can show the Project Explorer Window:

Window -> Show View -> Project Explorer

In this solution 'Project Explorer' will appear alongside the 'Package Explorer'