# running an existing project in eclipse setup

Tags: java, android, eclipse, blackberry

I received a full working project's sourcecode for an app written in java.
to set up my win7 machine I followed these steps:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/setup-your-java-development-environment-in-windows-7.html

i opened eclipse and need to work on this project, but have NO idea how to pull in the project with all its files so I can actually run it and test it.

I need to make changes to this project.

the folder is located in MyDocuments folder called Budget
within Budget I have:
.metadata
dev (see screenshot of what is in this folder)
[image]

can some one help me setup everything? I have never done this, I am only familiar with XAMPP

i also looked at 
[How to open an existing project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220633/how-to-open-an-existing-project-in-eclipse)

i tried it and get files and filders in the navigation pane, how from here?

Comment: please share the link from where u got the projects

Comment: I dont understand your last question. You say " tried it and get files and filders in the navigation pane". That sounds like: you successfully imported the project into your eclipse workspace. Now you can start working. So, what is the point?

Comment: LOL looks like i did import it sucessfully, but how do i run it now? sorry for the stupid q's but i have nec\ver worked in this kind of environment

Comment: why cant you run, if you have imported projects already ?

Comment: if you imported the project successfully, then right click the project and run.

Comment: thanks but i get an error stating "the selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches" ??

Answer (score 1):

What you have installed is JavaSE SDK plus a lot of other stuff for regular Java development. But in your screenshot I can see that your project has a Blackberry and Android versions. To develop in these platforms, your Java SDK install is not enough. You'll need to setup both BB and android development environments in your machine. You'll probably need:

For BlackBerry:

- Blackberry Java SDK (check which version was the BB subproject made for)
- Eclipse with BlackBerry Java plugin. There used to exist eclipse versions with the BB plugin  already installed available for download in Blackberry's site. If you don't have one, this is the one you want. And if you already have an eclipse, resist the temptation to just add the BB plugin to it. The BB plugin messes up with almost every other plugin you might already have. Also each plugin was made to a target eclipse version, so just download the bundled eclipse+plugin from BB and be happy:
  http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/download/
- Also some simulators for your target platform. I think the eclipse plugin comes with one already installed. They are really slow though, so you might want a real device instead.

For android:

- Android SDK
- An eclipse with the ADT plugin, if the project was made with eclipse, or the newer Android Studio. This eclipse plugin is better made than BB's so you won't need a dedicated eclipse like in BB's case.
- Simulators are made with the ADM tool included in the SDK.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for this info! i have eclipse installed sofar and pip and django mysql im going to run off xampp can i? i dont have a bb phone so will get the simulater. i do have an android phone handy :) it is for android that i have to develop further