# trying to run a BB and android project in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, blackberry

I followed these steps:

[How to import existing Android project into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse?rq=1)

which is:

File → Import → General → Existing Projects into Workspace → Next
Select root directory: /path/to/project
Projects → Select All
Uncheck Copy projects into workspace and Add project to working sets
Finish

then i followed:

["Selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches” when Eclipse for Android Project Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240333/selection-cannot-be-launched-and-there-are-no-recent-launches-when-eclipse-for)

which is: 
In the Package Explorer (the left column), right-click on the name of the project (the top item). In the menu that appears, select "Run as"; then choose "Android Application".

i dont have the android or blackberry application option i also get the error about selection cannot be launched...
all i have is:

[image]

i also added the blackberry plugin using eclipse
BlackBerry Java Plug-in Update Site - http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java

i have no idea what all is needed to run the projects. I have all the source code but dont know what i need to run it with

here is another post of mine which shows the folders i  have
[running an existing project in eclipse setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516697/running-an-existing-project-in-eclipse-setup)

Comment: Did you installed the ADT plugin ?  
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: ooh ok no, but buzy installing it now thanks

Comment: once i have followed the instructions in the link, what next pls?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html